# Snapshot isolation transaction failed in database '%.*ls' because the object accessed by the statement has been modified by a DDL statemen

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, availability-groups

We have a three node AlwaysOn availability group with Node 3 being used for reporting.  There is a job which runs on Node 3 and queries a bunch of tables and selects data out and it runs every three minutes.  This jobs fails randomly with the below error.

> Snapshot isolation transaction failed in database '%.*ls' because the
>   object accessed by the statement has been modified by a DDL statement
>   in another concurrent transaction since the start of this transaction.
>   It is disallowed because the metadata is not versioned. A concurrent
>   update to metadata can lead to inconsistency if mixed with snapshot
>   isolation.

Things I have checked

- we have SQL Audit that tracks DDL changes, so I have checked that and
  could not see any during the job failure.
- Look for any update statistics, Index Reorg/Rebuild job during that time

What else could be causing this error?

Comment: Can you please check [This BOL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933783.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) link. Look at the explanation section

Comment: Thanks, what does querying metadata mean?

Comment: you have to query metadata and have a  concurrent DDL statement that updates the metadata.  So I know there are no DDL's

Comment: Medata data here means system views or similar system objects

Comment: I'm betting something is being changed on the primary during that time that deals with those tables. Since the replica may be async, there is no telling how long it takes to redo or if anything is being blocked.

Comment: Be aware that TRUNCATE TABLE statements are considered DDL statements. I tried selecting from a read-only replica and truncate from the main server at the same time but could not re-create this error. But I'm pretty sure it's related to TRUNCATE somehow.